# Как установить шрифты на 7-ку?

Tags: windows, windows-7, администрирование

Есть каталог шрифтов TTF. нажимаю <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, далее контекстное меню, но про установку там ничего нет.

В разделе <kbd>Панель Управления → Шрифты</kbd> тоже нет ничего проустановку. Есть просмотр, удаление, какое-то скрывание. **Однако, если шрифт один, то в контекстном меню появляется пункт <kbd>Установить</kbd>**. Но как быть, когда шрифтов в списке много?

**P. S.** Даже копирование в каталог Fonts ни к чему не привело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот в этой [статейке](http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2012/05/24/ustanovka-shriftov-v-windows-7/) все описано

> Еще один способ установки шрифтовзаключается в том, что вам необходимооткрыть панель управления шрифтами(Control Panel\All Control PanelItems\Fonts) и простым перетягиванием(Drag&Drop) перетянуть файл шрифта  вэто окно.
>
> Если нужно установить сразунесколько шрифтов, то их так же простоможно выделить мышью и перетянуть напанель.

Answer (score 2):

В Windows 7 схожие по имени начертания (слово "гарнитура" здесь не совсем верно) шрифты автоматически группируются. Группу шрифтов можно открыть двойным щелчком по её иконке в окне "Шрифты" Панели управления. При этом надо понимать, что имя начертания часто отличается от имени файла шрифта, и находится внутри этого файла. Поэтому в группе однотипных шрифтов могут находиться несколько шрифтов с одинаковыми именами начертаний, но с разными именами файлов. В этом случае всегда работает только первый по списку имён начертаний. Кроме того, в Windows 7 некоторые шрифты неактивны (затенены серым) в зависимости от настроек региона.

Поэтому любой способ установки шрифтов в Windows 7 не всегда приводит к предсказуемым результатам.

**Что надо cделать:**

1. Разобраться с группами однотипных шрифтов и удалить оттуда ненужные, либо переименовать одноимённые (это можно сделать прогами типа FontManager).
2. Для включения всех шрифтов, независимо от настройки региона, надо в левой части окна "Шрифты" Панели управления нажать ссылку "Параметры шрифта", и в открывшемся окне снять флажок "Скрыть шрифты, основываясь на текущих параметрах языка".

Answer (score 1):

Просто скопируйте нужные вам файлы шрифтов в C:\Windows\Fonts (при условии что ваш системный диск именно С). Даже перезагружаться не надо. Если не поможет - однозначно проблема с системе, если ничего ценного нет - переустановите. Совет, конечно, так себе, но большего сказать не могу, так как пощупать проблемный комп тоже не могу.

Comment: Копировал, теперь они там, и обратно не удаляются!  Система их (скопированных не видит)  Комп не проблемный, проблемная новая (или уже старая Win7)  Раньше была кнопка "установить шрифт" В 7-ке ведь убрали! (типа более интуитивный и дружественный интерфейс.)  Системный администратор-программист с 12-летним стажем со шрифтом париться!

Comment: Я же копировал самым нормальным способом - Total Commander'om (ни кто с этим не поспорит)